# for loop does not increment correctly in C

Tags: c, for-loop

I am running a basic loop to check values on the upper diagonal elements of a two dimensional array:

```
//Check upper diagonal
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for (j = i+1; j<(n-1); j++){
        printf("n: %d i: %d j: %d\n",n, i, j);
        if (myA[i][j] > pow(10,-13)) return 0;
    }
}
```

However, this code does not accurately check the elements I want it to.  The print statement I placed in the inner loop gives the following output:

```
n: 4 i: 0 j: 1
n: 4 i: 0 j: 1
n: 4 i: 0 j: 2
n: 4 i: 1 j: 2
```

The particularly challenging part is between the first and second lines.  It seems j is not being incremented after the first iteration of the middle loop as I would expect it to be.

Why doesn't the second line of my output show `j: 2`?

Comment: I don't believe you! Show a complete program. Remove everything other than the loop and the printf. Remove the if. Should be 10 lines of code.

Comment: My guess is your `if` statement is `true` and you returning earlier than you think. If you provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) I am sure it make more sense.

Comment: Could it be that the entire section of code is running twice, and the second line is the start of the second run? That is, the first run of the for loops hit that `if` statement, it was true, and it returned.

Comment: Also, I think you could just do `1e-13` instead of calling `pow` every time.

Comment: TO all - Oops - Meant to type - What are the contents of `myA` (it has been a long day)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, the error does not occur with everything removed except the loop and the printf.  I will try to reproduce it including the function calls and array initialization.

Comment: @EricBaldwin jxh has the explanation. The main lesson you should learn is to make SSCCE and post that next time you have such a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second line of your output does not show `j: 2` because your loop was terminated by the `return 0`. The second line of your output is actually the result of another call on the function that contains this code.

You can easily test this by commenting out the `if` statement in the inner loop:

```
//Check upper diagonal
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for (j = i+1; j<(n-1); j++){
        printf("n: %d i: %d j: %d\n",n, i, j);
        //if (myA[i][j] > pow(10,-13)) return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct. I will use an SSCCE next time, my apologies.